# Doesn't set event on input when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote function, which control input text. When I click button, in Input set value. In that time I need  that function 'StartDate1.change' control change input value. So if this is value no equals 12/24/2013 -> clear field. But this is function doesn't work. Can you help me fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="demo_form.asp">
            Date: <input type="text" name="Phone" title="title1" value="">
            <input id="target" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" type="button"  accesskey="O" 
                   value="Add date" >
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( "#target" ).click(function() {
                    var StartDate=$('[title="title1"]');              
                    StartDate.val('12/25/2013');
                });

                var StartDate1=$('[title="title1"]');
                StartDate1.change(function(event){//doesn't get here
                    window.setInterval(function(){
                        if($(event.target).val()==='12/24/2013')
                        {
                            //some code
                        }else
                        {
                            $(event.target).val('');
                        }
                    });
                });


            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is example on fidler:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPYDJ/)

Comment: Pass 'delay' to window.setInterval and check when the callback to clear the text is called. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yPYDJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to control value in input field use `keyup` handler

http://jsfiddle.net/yPYDJ/5/

Comment: It's not work. Because some times input was enable. And only button can change text. That's why your code not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` event only fires when the value changes **and the input loses focus**.

You can trigger it manually changing your code like this:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  var StartDate=$('[title="title1"]');              
  StartDate.val('12/25/2013');
  StartDate.change();
});
```

Comment: No . I can't run this way, because button can't change onclick code.

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to window.setInterval is called repeatedly. So value set by the function on button click is reset immediately.

```
var timeFunction;                 
$( "#targetb" ).click(function() {
                    var StartDate=$('[title="title1"]'); 
                    StartDate.off('change');
                    StartDate.val('12/25/2013');
                    StartDate.on('change',function(event){
                    console.log("lol");
                    timeFunction=window.setInterval(clearInput,2000);
                });

                });

              function clearInput(){
                        var StartDate=$('[title="title1"]'); 
                        if(StartDate.val()==='12/24/2013')
                        {
                            //some code
                        }else
                        {
                            StartDate.val('');
                            window.clearInterval(timeFunction);
                        }

                    }
```

I have created a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yPYDJ/4/. Check this and accept it  ifthis is what you expected.

Comment: You are 12 seconds early I was about to click submit button :(

Comment: @dholakiyaankit I wish you to be earliest next time :) Hope you have validated my answer.

Comment: Ya obviously @ahamedmustafam

Comment: I can't modify $( "#targetb" ).click(function().

Comment: @user3132839 , you dont have to modify it. Add the new event handler. It will be called in sequence. http://jsfiddle.net/u9uaa/